# Приватноправовий та публічноправовий

Tags: терміни, правопис, разом-дефіс-окремо

Як слід писати "приватно(-)правовий" та "публічно(-)правовий" - разом або через дефіс? Згідно з Гуглом, "публічно-правовий" значно переважає над "публічноправовий", а ось "приватно-правовий" має слабку перевагу над "приватноправовий".